# New Email Subscriptions are not delivering in SQL Server 2005 Reporting services after migration

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have a problem with our new ssrs 2008 subscription not being sent out.
The old subscription work fine.

This happens since we migrated our ssrs server from Windows Server 2005/SSRS 2008 to a new vm with Windows Server 2008/SSRS 2008.

The main difference that I can see in the data table is that the new Subscription State field is 268435457 instead of 1 or 3.

So my server config should be fine since the old subscription are working fine, only the new subscription are not going out.

I have found someone with the same issue but no solution provided

[New Email Subscriptions are not delivering in SQL Server 2005 Reporting services](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9e1f1cde-e15a-48c3-8833-500d17d4a6bf/new-email-subscriptions-are-not-delivering-in-sql-server-2005-reporting-services?forum=sqlreportingservices)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was our mistake, since 3 employee worked on the problem, I could not see all that was done.

Then I activated the verbose logging and got an error.

The weird thing is that the error did not show up in the log until the verbose setting was used. The error should have been added to the logs at the 'info' level

> schedule!WindowsService_ .... :: Error processing
>   event 'TimedSubscription', data =
>   .... , error =
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportServerStorageException:
>   An error occurred within the report server database.  This may be due
>   to a connection failure, timeout or low disk condition within the
>   database. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The INSERT
>   statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_Notifications_Subscriptions". The conflict occurred in database
>   "ReportServer", table "dbo.Subscriptions_OLD", column
>   'SubscriptionID'.

When we troubleshooted something else someone renamed the 'Subscription' table to 'Subscription_Old', and created a new 'Subscription' evrything worked fined except for the scheduled reports

Comment: How did you solve the problem. I'm getting the same thing. There are two tables "Subscriptions" and "Subscriptions1". My error says it is using "Subscriptions1" table, but I don't see any FKs in "Subscriptions1".

Comment: We simply removed the new table and fixe the relation in the old table that contained the FK

Comment: Thanks, I recreated the FK contraints in ActiveSubscriptions and Notifications to reference the original Subscriptions table. Even though these two tables were set to use Subscriptions1's id as FK, Subscriptions was still being used by SSRS.